# Working with Dynamic Keys in a Typescript Class using Generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm running into an issue with the type system in TS when using `extends keyof`.
In this case I have a `TreeContent` object, however I want the tree to allow dynamic keys of where the data it is held in the tree object that the constructor uses.

I'm calling the class like so

```
const tree = new Tree<
            TestTree,
            "children",
            "data",
            TestTreeData,
            "label"
        >(treeTestData, "children", "data", "label");
```

The `children` key is to access the children data inside of the `TestTree` and the same with `data` and `label`, however, `label` will be used to find the `label` inside the `TestTreeData`. My aim here is to create a flexible class that can construct an n-ary tree from tree data that could use different aliases for children and the data it stores.

```
export class Tree<
    TreeContent,
    ChildKey extends keyof TreeContent,
    DataKey extends keyof TreeContent,
    Data,
    LabelKey extends keyof Data
>

{
    id: string;
    children: NodeModel<Data>[];
    childrenKey: ChildKey;
    dataKey: DataKey;
    labelKey: LabelKey;
    data: Data;

constructor(
        treeContent: TreeContent,
        _childrenKey: ChildKey,
        _dataKey: DataKey,
        _labelKey: LabelKey,
        _id = uuidv4()
    ) {
        this.dataKey = _dataKey;
        this.childrenKey = _childrenKey;
        this.labelKey = _labelKey;
        this.children = [];
        this.id = _id;

       if (
           !(_childrenKey in treeContent) ||
           !Array.isArray(treeContent[this.childrenKey])
          ) {
              throw Error(`Could not find data in ${String(this.childrenKey)}`);
          }

          const children = treeContent[this.childrenKey];

}
```

I omitted some of the other code in the constructor because I don't feel like it's relevant to the problem.

The issue is that children is `const children: TreeContent[ChildKey]` is not a type of an array even though I explicitly check if it's an array. I'm aware I can cast it however, I'm trying my best to avoid casting in my case. If that's the option I'm left with then that's fine but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

I may be coming at this the completely wrong way, which I suspect.

What I want is that I can inform TS that I expect the value of `const children: TreeContent[ChildKey]` to become `const children: TreeContent[]`
Then I could replicate the logic with the `DataKey` but TreeContent[DataKey] should equal a Generic data object.

EDIT:
Here is a TS [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5lVCKDeAUMicgCZxhwBcam2uEAIpXANzGkIAWwANmVwha6LDjwBtALocAvoUKhIsRClEM8LKsiKlkwMrSxRQAcw56%20cAEYQ%20RsCZDnC8wggD2ILMkhjGWjR0-njIALw6nCQUVLS6eqQGtABEAIzJADRRCVa29sgA5ACiAB5wALYADnwQqQXZsll6PPyCEMLIEtl68QkJMUG9fcNJyMkATJndwzOWNna0xWVVNXUKs6SN030tAkK0XRt9Q0f9rHHbp1e5C4WlFdW1BVmXV4mGYwAsU299W78JXZtDrSJq-f5HKRgv7QhInYYDC4A0bJADMP1%20N3ySweq3qr02sJmQP2nQJx3Js0RkQBMxR3yJtJIWMW9xWT3WTOQEKZJPaB0pMykgs2lOFM3kemFbgQVgwGDQjAAPNlxBAAMJeSDgZAQErasgKjzWABWEAQYFh6t4AgA0hAAJ66-XtQ3IADWjo8MEVeE14HaluygXtTr1BoVnod3t9Gq1gdhgVhABl5nxQ86Ix6vT7AoQAHyEIZ8jpq-3asDSCxcG3A0O0a2tUPV6KsevIEOOlvILHt1N5ZvZamBDjZTzeRwAVwtHigAApLo4-fHwCJGOWE5cAPol9uNu2OxkkLcDdudh1H5Bb3uO2j9uyh2EAShpwzAvAwADpT47wlefw63Z6O%20wBfruv4RDutZCIOMwgV%20N5OpBiFAaQ8GfiWf5VpyfTAD6C6nAAhHOUGtDBv6gL464rmAL4AD50ZShEAIJQFAcAOp%20oGsexDpzkucYBuAEjoeBDpSE%20lwvvCfTvlAHgAO7IEUbGznOAAGmqTgIyAgB4YDIDAoBkOQrD6CAyAACT4AAyo4Zj8R%20GHQe0oZPrI6lPqhJBuMSXg%20JhEQCRuwmiS5IChjIOGAuFn6VJOGDcHOXnRXoeHIHOxEnm2FEWcFNFPtJlJyYpymqfOmkeNpJl6QZRkgCZAzmVZtn2c4JEAe5nnedyqVoU5TVBdRQmVtlVCRcgcAKiODSuMQxAwJOIAWsAXjIAguCUBAarJa%20JDjj4Al-iAEBKWqKqnOoaqXnoyQlhiGzJAMD2zFdASsDdpDJFiySXPm-H0GqSZjPdGRjM9YPfWmyQpb1QA) with an error showing that I can't use the push function.

Comment: Please provide a [mre], ideally one that can just be pasted into the [TypeScript playgrond](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play) without triggering compilation errors.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WJx3kN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Sort of, I also tried this approach. Problem here is that the Record<ChildKey, TreeContent[]> would mean that it expects every key in the record to be "children" and the content to be TreeContent[] if I'm not mistaken. However I want to inform that it should also have a key of "data" that has a value of the generic Data. The fix that you included casts the TreeContent[] as Data, I'm wondering if I can get typescript to know that there should be a "data" field with a generic "data" in it.

Comment: If I understand you correctly then you are mistaken; `T extends Record<K, T[]>` doesn't mean that *every* key has to be `K`, it just means that it has to have *at least* `K` as a key and the property there must be of a type assignable `T[]`.  Also I didn't "cast" `TreeContent[]` as `Data` (the term "assert" is more conventional in TS, btw), you did.  I can fix that too like [this](//tsplay.dev/mblrbw) but that required removing a type parameter and is a separate issue (they both happen in your code but they are distinct problems). How should we proceed from here?

Comment: Sorry I think I must've of gotten confused about which version I was looking at with the asserting as Data. I had a few different versions up comparing solutions.

Comment: So are you saying that in the record that it must have at least the ChildKey with a value of TreeContent[]? Again maybe I'm misunderstanding something here. Would it be possible to say that it must at least have ChildKey with a value of TreeContent[] and also have a DataKey with a value of Data? Seems like the solution you posted works but I feel like I'm not fully understanding how this this.data = treeContent[_dataKey]; is working. Sorry I feel that I'm clearly missing something here.

Comment: I removed `Data` from your code; you don't need it. I used `TreeContent[DataKey]` instead, so there's no need to constrain `TreeContent` further. If you had needed a `Data` type parameter, then you could say `TreeContent extends Record<ChildKey, TreeContent[]> & Record<DataKey, Data>`. But the code shown doesn't motivate the need for an extra type parameter.  So now, uh, what can we do here? I'm hoping to write up an answer instead of continuing to explain in comments. If something is not working with my code for your use cases, please [edit] the question to show the use case that fails.

Comment: Yes it seems you're correct. A fully written up answer to this would be helpful. It think you're correct, I don't think the code warrants the`& Record<DataKey, Data>`  I couldn't find anything like the question I asked, so I think your answer would clear it up for other people too. Many thanks.

Comment: Okay I'll do so when I get a chance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have that the `ChildKey` and `DataKey` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters are [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to be keys of the `TreeContent` type parameter.

You don't have any further constraints on the type of value at the `DataKey` key, so there's no apparent reason for you to have a `Data` type parameter all all; instead you can just use the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) `TreeContent[DataKey]` to refer to the type you were calling `Data`.

On the other hand, you need to constrain the type of value at the `ChildKey` key so that it is an array of `TreeContent`.  You can do this by constraining `TreeContent` to `Record<ChildKey, TreeContent[]>`, using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type).  (This doesn't mean that `TreeContent` can't have more properties than just `ChildKey`; object types are open in TS and are allowed to have more properties than mentioned.  It just means that `ChildKey` has to be one of the keys, and its property must be assignable to `TreeContent[]`.

Once you make those changes, things should start behaving as desired:

```
class Tree<
    TreeContent extends Record<ChildKey, TreeContent[]>,
    ChildKey extends keyof TreeContent,
    DataKey extends keyof TreeContent,
    LabelKey extends keyof TreeContent[DataKey]
>{
    children: TreeContent[];
    childrenKey: ChildKey;
    dataKey: DataKey;
    labelKey: LabelKey;
    data: TreeContent[DataKey];

    constructor(treeContent: TreeContent, _childrenKey: ChildKey,
        _dataKey: DataKey, _labelKey: LabelKey ) {
        this.dataKey = _dataKey;
        this.childrenKey = _childrenKey;
        this.labelKey = _labelKey;
        this.children = [];
    
        const children = treeContent[this.childrenKey];
        // const children: TreeContent[ChildKey]    
        children.push(); // okay
    
        this.data = treeContent[_dataKey]; // okay
    }
}

function createTree() {
    const tree = new Tree(testTreeData, "children", "data", "label");
    // const tree: Tree<TestTree, "children", "data", "label">
}
```

Looks good. Note that you don't need to manually specify the type arguments when calling the `Tree` constructor.  The compiler infers them correctly for you automatically.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoQM5lVCKDeAUMicgCZxhwBcam2uEAIpXANzGkIAWwANmVwha6LDjwBtALocAvoUKhIsRClEM8LKsiKlkwMrSxRQAcw56+cAEYQ+RsCZDnC8wggD2ILMkhjGWjR0-njIALw6nCQUVLS6eqQGtABEAIzJADRRCVa29sgA5ACiAB5wALYADnwQqQXZsll6PPyCEMLIEtl68QkJMUG9fcNJyMkATJndw5Y2drTFZVU1dQozeo3TfS0CQrRd68NDh30DcVsnfbnzhaUV1bUFWReXeqPJACxTr8ObP9u8XbtfZSJr-P4nUEXCF9Y7DM6Rf76QxjADM33+13yi3uK3qL1IMPWOzaHQO-zhPwRlKRyJSXzBtJyc2xd2WjzWTOQRKRJL2nQJhykgoS8kuwpmYtIwrcCCsGAwaEYAB5suIIABhLyQcDICAlHVkRUAJQgnigZGVGsBZAA0hAAJ4ZJV4LXgdpgaQAPkZyGtrXtDr1BvaRuQAGtHR4YC7NdqPb7AoHg4bFZGHdHY26dWBfQAZFnJ-WpiNRmPq7MeiRJx3Cr1DPnArPx8DSCxcG1CQO0f0CQPt6KsbvIGsOgfILHDgt5fvZBEVlue0cyTkkTzeRwAVwQYA8UAAFBdHK7FyJGJXwL69AB9RsgYe9u2Oq+ka8DYejl8ka+Tx20ad2IGvoAJSIsMYC8BgAB076OuEyBvkOjrjnoEHANBd7JhEt6du0s4zGh0G-kG2HEShpCEVBd7wW2q4JMAMaHpcACE+44a0XZwaAvjnouoEAD78SKzEAIJQFAcAOlB6FiRJDr7secbuq2lGYbWwEXKBNKodwUAeAA7sgRTiXu+4AAZapuAjICAHhgMgMCgGQ5CsPoIDIAAJPgADKjhmApkFUbh96OsBshmcB5EkG4Mzrj41ERIpF6eqpwWBiuMwAPSZcgcX2XeZ4nspnqPuldHNMFUGVJuGDcPukXINlyAeOGknlYkjGsYhVDJtxSV8VpIoQXphnGXpB4WR4VnObZ9mOSAzkDG5nk+X5zhsbBDphRFUXcu1JCUUtiW8cVEjdXA6W7U1LVtRsrgKDAm4gDuwBeLluCUBA6r1WBa5eD4inwSAECGd9fgaMwrDOskd6ZGMAxw8kWLJJF2RNQAtJjWPY9jXrIAAeoT+PkF4BT2cDEDObuyAYJUZoMUGEGYCgYAOnTyBwFApgYM6NT2UzuUeFU-DQG5MCi0z5T3UAA)

Comment: Brilliant write up, thank you for the help. I would upvote but I've not got the rep for it. I've accepted as the answer though.